# How do I put only one SIM card in dual-SIM smartphone to "Airplane mode"?

Tags: battery-life, dual-sim, airplane-mode

In Airplane Mode, the device lasts noticably longer. The "Cell standby" shows 76% in battery settings.

There are two SIM cards inserted into the device, but now I only use the second. I expect that if I disable the first SIM card, it should consume less power. I don't want to remove the SIM from the phone though, as it's easy to get lost or to forget it when needed.

How do I disable (as in "Airplane mode") only one of two SIM cards on Android? If there is no proper way, can it be done by some root trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the very first configuration menu item: "SIM card management".

There are checkboxes to enable first and second SIM cards, as well as to choose which card is used for data and for calls/messages.