# Dual SIM phone: Disable/Enable SIM card on Airplane Mode

Tags: dual-sim, airplane-mode

I have a Samsung M32 (current Android version: 11, Knox version: 3.7).

I'm using dual SIMs, 1 for homeland and 1 for the overseas. I want to ENABLE the overseas SIM and DISABLE the homeland SIM when I get on the plane after turning ON the Airplane mode. The reason is, if I turn on the overseas SIM beforehand, I will have to pay a daily usage charge in my homeland and vice versa (I have to pay a daily usage charge for homeland when the airplane lands on another country).

Is there any software solution to this or should I disregard the dual SIMs and use the phone as single SIM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [How do I put only one SIM card in dual-sim smartphone to "Airplane mode"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127596/44325).

Comment: AFAIK, Airplane mode will disable telephony service no matter what. While it's possible to manually turn on WiFi and Bluetooth back after turning it on, there's no way to enable any SIM on Airplane mode.

Comment: Thank you for comments. 
"How do I put only one SIM card in dual-sim smartphone to "Airplane mode" is asking to enable/disable SIM cards without the airplane mode. My question is enable/disable during the airplane mode.
On the other hand, as you've commented; I'm trying to find to disable one SIM in Airplane mode in which I can not understand why this option is not available.

Comment: This is a super valid use case and I'm surprised that not more people encounter this. It makes you think that nobody who actually relies on dual SIM for multiple countries/continents was involved in designing the dual SIM UI. It should be noted that you can change the SIM preference for calls and texts in airplane mode, but not for mobile data. The only "solution" to avoid charges seems to be turning off airplane mode at 30,000 ft to make the switch without connecting, which is obviously nothing you should do.